Notes and PDF symbols not appearing in helm-bibtex
I have set values of bibtex-completion-bibliography, bibtex-completion-notes-path and bibtex-completion-library-path in a .dir-locals.el file. The .dir-locals file looks like this:
;;; Directory Local Variables            -*- no-byte-compile: t -*-
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((nil . ((bibtex-completion-library-path . "~/Dropbox/reading/book-pdfs")
         (bibtex-completion-notes-path . "~/Dropbox/reading/book-notes")
         (bibtex-completion-bibliography . "~/Dropbox/reading/books.bib"))))

I do this because I want to be able to use helm-bibtex for different projects, each of which has its own directory.
When I call up helm-bibtex the bibliography appears, but the notes and PDF symbols do not. I know that notes and PDFs exist, if I assign values in my init.el file these symbols appear. The values of bibtex-completion-notes-symbol and bibtex-completion-pdf-symbol are correct when verified with C-h v.
Has anyone got any ideas on why these symbols aren't showing up?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Please add your .dir-locals.el file to your question.

@NickD, my .dir-locals.el file added to the question.
